# Check if a word occur in string and not to be in first and last

Tags: php

I am trying to check if word is occur in a string but not to be the first and last word, if its true then remove the space after and before of the word and replace with a underscore.

Input:

```
$str = 'This is a cool area";
```

Output:

```
$str = 'This is a_cool_area";
```

I want to check that the word 'cool' is inside the string but not a first and last word. if yes the remove the space & replace with '_'

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) to do this job, using this regex:

```
/(?<=\w)\s+(' . $word . ')\s+(?=\w)/i
```

which looks for the word, surrounded by at least one word character on either side (to prevent matching at the beginning or ending of the sentence). Usage in PHP:

```
$str = 'This is a cool area';
$word = 'cool';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)\s+(' . $word . ')\s+(?=\w)/i', '_$1_', $str);
echo $str . "\n";
$str = ' Cool areas are cool ';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)\s+(' . $word . ')\s+(?=\w)/i', '_$1_', $str);
echo $str . "\n";
```

Output:

```
This is a_cool_area
 Cool areas are cool
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NhlC6)

Comment: Instead of checking for word characters on either side, you could check that the word isn't immediately after `^` or immediately before `$`, which match the start and end of the string, respectively.

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco I did consider that, but if there are spaces at the beginning or end of the string (e.g. https://3v4l.org/h0GmR) it wouldn't work. I was trying to be more robust with this solution.

Comment: Well, in that case you could remove those spaces with `trim`

Comment: @AlejandroDeCicco true, but I want to return the string *exactly* as it was passed in other than changing spaces to `_` where required.

Comment: if I have a '+*' instead of space, where we have to add that in this?

Comment: @Amrutha where I have `\s+` in the regex, you would replace that with `\+`

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkWord($str, $word) 
{
  $arr = explode(" ", $str);
  $newArr = array_slice($arr, 1, -1);
  $key = array_search($word, $newArr);
  if($key !== false)
  {
      return implode('_',array_slice($arr, $key, 3));
  }
  else
  {
      return $str;
  }
}



echo checkWord('This is a cool area', 'cool');
```